# Why Qt with CmakeList is not able to lo load imported QML component in Design Tab?

Tags: qt, cmake, qml

I have a project in 5.12 in which is with pro file.
I have put below lines in pro file

"QML_IMPORT_PATH = blablabla

QML_DESIGNER_IMPORT_PATH = blablabla"

then I can see any of the custom imporeted QML in Design.

what is the similar way to do this in cmakeList projects after 5.14 ?

Comment: I think you have to put these as environment variables in your profile (or bashrc) or put them on the command line when opening qt creator, whichever suites you

Comment: Thanks @Amfasis;  Here some of the components which are part of a plugin. I have imported the plugin path  in my qml file. But I am getting this error " QML module does not contain information about components contained in plugins."